# How do we know what the truth about Israel really is?

Tags: messiah, state-of-israel, holocaust-shoah, zionism, yom-haatzmaut

I went to a class about the various different Orthodox Jewish stances on the State of Israel. In the class, the Rabbi gave 5 different such stances.This ranged from #1 being religiously anti-State of Israel to #5 being religiously pro-State of Israel.
The Rabbi presented each one with what seemed to be the same enthusiasm. He cited proofs from different Gedolim from throughout Jewish history. Tannoim, Amoroim, Geonim, Rishonim and Acharonim who support each stance. One thing that each of these different stances have in common is that they all say that they are correct and that the truth is hard to find. They also say that if you don't believe in their opinions, you will be punished. #5 said that if you are anti-Zionist, you wont come back with Moshiach. #1 said that if you are Zionist, you are contributing to a terrible holocaust that Hashem will punish us for having the State of Israel. How do I know who to believe if, a) I want to come back with Moshiach and b) I don't want to contribute to a terrible holocaust?

Comment: what do your rebbeim think or say? perhaps you should ask them. if you follow your mesorah-tradition recieved from your rebbe, you wont be culpable for the result.

Comment: I don't think "Which side in XYZ ongoing machlokes is correct?" is really an answerable question. After all, there must be people who hold each position, otherwise there wouldn't be a machlokes to begin with.

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us some of the proofs for each stance. I dont think anyone is as extreme as you make them. So you really have nothing to worry about. It is at the moment in the daf yomi of kesubos where all this 'fuss' is created. It depends if you take the gemoro literally or not.

Comment: Welcome to the world of religion.. It doesn't seem like you're lacking information, and I don't think this site is for guidance.. What's wrong with taking an approach of "there are 5 approaches to this matter", or just don't worry about it too much and you'll find yourself gravitate toward the approach that best matches your instincts.

Comment: It worries some people about whether or not they are following the correct path. I was hoping for some feedback about what to do but it seems that all people can give criticism.

Comment: The question is too broad. Pick a specific detail you heard in the lecture, and ask about it here. I can think of several different pro-State of Israel approaches off the top of my head- and one of them is anti-Zionist despite being hawkishly pro-Israel! So see if you can narrow down your question.

Comment: Joshua, we aren't trying to be critical for the sake of criticism. What you're asking (mediate between a longstanding dispute among gedolim) is really outside the purview of what we do on this site. Personally, I have a philosophy that as long as you're performing your hishtadlut earnestly then you can be confident that you're at least being steered in the right direction personally...

Comment: who cares. just follow the shulchan aruch and leave the rest to God. Teyku